# Logs are flooded with requests to reporting server for POST /~/v75/reporting/remotedatasourceproxy/

Tags: paas, reporting

We installed a new 9.2 solution on PAAS (including SXA 1.9 - although that does not seem to be relevant). This is a clean solution that will be filled with content -and code- from an upgraded version.

As soon as we added our content, the log files started flooding with post requests to the reporting server: `POST /~/v75/reporting/remotedatasourceproxy/`. And flooding can be taken literally as our App Insights went over it's limit every day. (ok, the limit was still very low but I just don't want millions of lines saying it did a post request).

After a while we can see some pattern in the requests:
[image]

We can see similar patterns on all our environments. Note that the image is just showing those post requests... There is no traffic on the CD servers, CM is used to alter some content.

The web logs showed us that the requests come from the CM or the CD server.
Where do those requests come from on how do I stop them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the requests come from the `sitecore_suggested_test_index`. With the correct filter on the logs we could see that the start of the calls was always preceded by `Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_suggested_test_index`.

Sitecore has a task that schedules the rebuild/update of the suggested test index that can be found in `/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/Content Testing/`. After we changed the schedule as desribed on https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/287674 to 1 (or even 7) day(s) instead of every hour, we had much less requests: replace `20140101|99990101|127|1:00:00` with `20140101|99990101|127|1.00:00`.

Apparently these requests are "normal" behavior. They are initiated in the `Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestPotentialMetricBase` class, which is a base class for the computed fields `TestImpactMetric`, `TestPotentialMetric`, and `TestRecommendationMetric` which are used in the suggested test index.

So you migth want to lower that index schedule as well ;)